# Android SQLite Database: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm implementing a app, and I like to use the SQLite Database to store some informations by a user. I need to the id = 0 in the database to everytime update the same line.

```
user.clean() = Clear all the values stored in database (row with id = 0);
user.save() = update the values in the database (row with id = 0);
user.load() = get all the values from the database (row with id = 0);
```

My problem is: The app don't reads anything from the database, and I have not a exceptions in the logcat.

My class:

```
/**
* This class is used to manage the user information.
*/
public class User extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOCAL_DB_NAME = "local_db";
    private static final int LOCAL_DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String USER_DB_TABLE = "local_user";
    public static final String[] USER_ALL_COLUMNS = {"id", "name","email","birthday","country","credential","purchased","params"};
     private static final String CREATE_LOCAL_DB = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + USER_DB_TABLE + 
        "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, email TEXT, birthday TEXT, country TEXT, credential TEXT, purchased TEXT, params TEXT)";


    public User(Context context){
        super(context, LOCAL_DB_NAME, null, LOCAL_DB_VERSION);
        this.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_LOCAL_DB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(User.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_DB_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private String name = "example";
    private String birthday = "10-12-2000";
    private String country = "br";
    private String credential = "xxxxxxxx";
    private String email = "xxxxx@xxxxxx";
    private String purchased = "xxxxxxx";
    private String params = "xxxx";

    // This method saves the this user instance in the local database.
    public void save(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("id", 0);
        values.put("name", this.name);
        values.put("email", this.email);
        values.put("birthday", this.birthday);
        values.put("country", this.country);
        values.put("credential", this.credential);
        values.put("purchased", this.purchased);
        values.put("params", this.params);

        try{
            db.update(USER_DB_TABLE, values,  "id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(0) });
        }catch (Exception e){
            db.insert(USER_DB_TABLE, null, values);
        }

        db.close();

    }

    // This method cleans the local user stored in the database.
    public void clean() {

        this.name = "";
        this.birthday = "";
        this.country = "";
        this.credential = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.purchased = "";
        this.params = "";

        this.save();
    }

    // This method loads the user stored in the database.
    public void load() {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.query(USER_DB_TABLE, USER_ALL_COLUMNS, "id =?",
                   new String[] { String.valueOf(0) }, null, null, null, null);

       if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
          this.name = cursor.getString(1);
          this.birthday = cursor.getString(2);
          this.country = cursor.getString(3);
          this.credential = cursor.getString(4);
          this.email = cursor.getString(5);
          this.purchased = cursor.getString(6);
          this.params = cursor.getString(7);
       }else{
          this.clean();
       }
       db.close();
    }
}
```

-------------------------------Solved ------------------------------------------

I have changed only the first id to 1, and works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

this.name = cursor.getString(1);
```

The cursor is empty. You should check the result of `moveToFirst()` and only call the `get...()` if it returns `true`:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    this.name = cursor.getString(1);
    ...
} else {
    // reset variables to empty/defaults
}
```

(Checking for `cursor != null` is not necessary though it's a good habit.)

Comment: if (cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
                this.name = cursor.getString(1); ...
            } ????

Comment: This change stop the exception, but the app continue reading anything from the database ... :(

Comment: Could you rephrase that, I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Im using this code to read the value and print in textview, using the onCreateView of a fragment: User user = new User(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(user.getName());

Comment: Ok, I believe you need an else branch there: if no row was found in db, reset the object fields such as `name` to reasonable empty/default values.

Comment: Question Updated. Iaalto, in the load method have clean() to clean and save in the database. The save method haves a try/catch if no row was found in db...

Comment: I have changed only the first id to 1, and works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

cursor.moveToPosition(position);

Comment: I have changed only the first id to 1, and works perfectly. Thanks.